# changing index position on startDrag()

Tags: actionscript-3

I am making a dragable map and there are few thing on top of the map(UI). When the map is double clicked it enables drag. But it's changing the index position, basically, it going over the UI. what's the easiest way to control the index position of the map?
The click and drag event is controlled in mapZoom class.

```
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, enableDrag);

public function enableDrag(e:MouseEvent):void
```

{ 
  this.startDrag();
 }

Answer (score 1):

i think the best way is to add two children to your root (main) clip. thee use the first (that is always below the second) for the map and the second for UI